# ssl challenge response

Tags: security

Does the SSL protocol require a challenge to check whether the subjected machine has access to its private key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend reading the paper [A first few milliseconds of an HTTPS connection](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html).   It describes the handshake quite well.  You can also fire up wireshark and follow along.

Answer (score 1):

Only in 2 way authentication. Take a peek at this [image](http://computer.yourdictionary.com/images/computer/SSL.GIF) for the "standard" SSL handshaking and note the lack of a client private key (none is needed). In the 2 way authentication handshake the client must prove it's identity in the same way the server does as per that diagram.

In general the client doesn't need a private key since symmetric keys are created after the servers identity is verified.